# Jenkins external-monitor-job setup

Tags: jenkins, cron

I'm novice to Jenkins. I want to make Jenkins to monitor my crons. I'm following the official tutorial:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs

Jenkins is running on AWS Ubuntu 14. The installation was fine and I can access Jenkins on 9091. 
http://www.example.com:9091/

External Monitor Job Plugin was installed by default. It can be found in the Plugin Manager.

What I did so far.
On Jenkins I created new External job called "backup". http://www.example.com:9091/job/backup/ and basically that's all there.

In my cron file: "/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root":

```
MAILTO=example@gmail.com
JENKINS_HOME=http://www.example.com:9091
* * * * *     export JENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME; java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins-core-2.7.1.jar "backup" backup.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

Because of the `mailto` settings initially I was receiving `no jenkins-core-*.jar found error`. I started looking for `jenkins-core-*.jar` but I didn't find one. In my "/usr/share/jenkins" folder there was only `jenkins.war` file. I unzipped the .war file and copied the following files to it's folder:

```
jenkins-core-*.jar
remoting-*.jar
ant-1.7.0.jar
commons-io-1.4jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
jna-posix-*.jar
xstream-*.jar
```

After I did this I started to receive more complicated error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at hudson.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:222)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 13 more
```

As expected there is noting on the Jenkins side. Obviously I'm missing something. I tryed to remove quotes around `"backup"` and to change the command `backup.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null` with something I'm sure is working. For example: `cd /my/directory && program myfile.file` but this is all. I'm wondering if I have to unzip the whole .war file somewhere or if I need to follow different path? I'm not sure what the error means. I found suggestion it's messing up with Tomcat. Please for some help with this.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what this issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Which java and jenkins version are you using?

I had my jenkins configured and working properly without any problems but after one upgrade I started to have the same error

My environment is:

- Debian 8
- jenkins 2.13
- java 1.7.0_101 (IcedTea)

Comment: I am using more or less the same configuration and also after an upgrade around 2016-05-11 it started to fail.

Did you find any permanent solution or workaorund?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement a workaround by downgrading Jenkins to 2.2.

According to [this page](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35184?focusedCommentId=259584&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-259584) ServletContextListener was introduced in 2.3. I grabbed an old WAR from [here](http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/war/), I then used the [Digital Ocean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-jenkins-for-continuous-development-integration-on-centos-7) for installing from a WAR.

For reference, I'm using Centos 7 and Java 1.8.0_101

Hopefully a more permanent solution is out there.

Comment: After spending many hours on this issue, finally I moved all my stuff to Freestyle project item. Its much more convenient and easy way, moreover I didn't have so much lines to manage.